# Repair input/output error on directory

Tags: directory, io, inode

I'm having an issue with a input/output error on an external drive that is formatted ExFAT. I was trying to delete some files off my external drive and it was giving me the input/output error.

I ran `fsck.exfat` and it returns me the following;

```
exfatfsck 1.2.3
WARN: volume was not unmounted cleanly.
Checking file system on /dev/sdc5.
File system version           1.0
Sector size                 512 bytes
Cluster size                128 KB
Volume size                1210 GB
Used space                 1196 GB
Available space              14 GB
ERROR: expected 1 continuations.
Totally 27000 directories and 240173 files.
File system checking finished. ERRORS FOUND: 1.
```

This one directory which I use for storing Steam games in was having issues of letting me run the game, so I tried to delete the game contents, but it won't delete this one directly because it complains about a nonexistent file that's usually contained inside this directory. This Steam game in particular is Rocket League, and the folder is;

`rocketleague/TAGame/CookedLinux`

if I run `ls` against the directory I get this;

```
$ ls -la
ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error
total 0

$ sudo rm -rvf *
rm: cannot remove 'CookedLinux': Input/output error
```

I think I've dealt with a similar issue to this once before, but I do not know how to fix this. I think this is similar to a broken inode issue where it thinks a certain file exists, but doesn't exist.

Comment: I experienced this and found this question, thinking that my HDD was bad.  Turns out the `/` drive was full and somehow copying *out* of there caused this error.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sudo apt install testdisk
sudo testdisk /dev/sdc
```

PS. I would predict that your HDD will fail permanently in max few weeks. Would consider backup.

Comment: The likeliness of my external hard drive failing in a few weeks from a broken inode seems very unlikely.

Comment: inodes don't just brake by theirselves... if you consider it unlikely, don't backup... but don't cry after losing ALL data :)

Comment: This conversation [has been moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49961/discussion-between-terdon-and-flash-thunder).